# How to add number below 1 (decimal) onto the end of a number in c#

Tags: c#, math, calculator

Hi sorry for the bad title, but this has got me stumped and I need some help. I am making a calculator program in C# that has a GUI. In order to use the GUI I need to make it so that a number is created by clicking numbers one at a time (If this doesn't make any sense here is an example: Person presses 1 then 2 the calculator displays 12. The way I achieved this is by having `var[varIndex] = (var[varIndex] * 10) + 1` if the key being pressed is 1 where var is an array of the totals entered.

So what I need to do now is append a decimal onto the end so what I have done so far is set a boolean that will be true if the decimal button is selected switching all the number buttons mode to decimal, so now I need a formula that will add a number onto the end past a decimal (for example: Person presses 1 then . then 2 then 5 they will get 1.25) I can't find a formula for this though!

So my question is what formula will append a number on the end for a decimal.

Will i have to gut my program and make it take in text then convert to the numbers? Or is there a formula? Thanks a ton and sorry for the terrible explanation.

Comment: why not just treat it as a string until you're ready to do some sort of calculation?

Comment: I agree with @Jonesy, you just have to make sure they don't add in a "." more than once.

Comment: I agree with @Jonesy - this should be text until you need to do the calculation

Comment: @Jonesy I should have done that but I don't want to gut all the code I already have so if there is a solution then great but if not then I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonesy (and others) mentioned in the comments, this would be a lot easier if you stored the current number as a string and appended characters to it, and then use `Double.TryParse(..)` to turn it into a number.

However, if you're determined to treat it as a number, you can simply do something along the following lines:

```cs
var[varIndex] += enteredNumber / (10 * numEntriesSinceDecimal);
```

`numEntriesSinceDecimal` would start at 0, and increment with each button the user pressed.

Comment: Thanks! I think I might do what Jonesy said as it will make it easier to work with in the future, but your solution is the one I needed. I'll accept your answer once it allows me.

Comment: Great! I'm always glad when people choose to do things the right way, even if it's a bit more work upfront, rather than continuing along the path of least resistance.  Doing so might seem like a great idea, but you'll almost always end up cornering yourself into a local-minimum and make things harder for yourself in the future.